# PostSharp code contract for GreaterThan does not fire when the values are equal

Tags: code-contracts, postsharp

when using postsharp code contracts I have set a **GreaterThan** attribute to 
**0**. I have an action with an id decorated with the GreaterThan contract

```
   public virtual ActionResult Edit([GreaterThan(0)] int id)
```

when I call the http://localhost/Items/Edit/-1, I get the following error

> *The parameter 'id' must be greater than 0. Parameter name: id*

when I call the http://localhost/Items/Edit/0 , I do not get that error.

It seems to be that the paramter is GreaterThan *or equal to*. I could set it to .5, but then my error message looks weird because it would say *The parameter 'id' must be greater than 0.5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a bit of a naming clumsiness.

There are two constraints: `GreaterThan` and `StrictlyGreaterThan`. I think that this information clarifies it :-) - you have to use `StrictlyGreaterThan` in your use case.

Yes, "greater than" is a strict inequality and "greater than or equal" is a non-strict one, so naming of `GreaterThan` is incorrect.

Well, we know about it, but it's not possible to change APIs after they go public. So this funny mind bending issue is actually a feature...

Answer (score 1):

If it's a bug AND your number is going to be zero, then you could try using:

"*StrictlyPositive*", whihch *Requires a value strictly greater than 0*.

This is not a good solution, I know, but for now.